# Is it possible to disable camera sway and/or weapon bobbing in Quake 1?

Tags: health, quake

Upon sorting some of my games into categories on Steam I realised I had the original Quake in my Steam library (bought as part of a Steam sale pack no doubt), and decided to give it a go.

Unfortunately there is something about Quake's bobbing/camera movement which makes me motion sick. I can't stand to play it for more than 5 minutes at a time before I need to take a break. This is a weird phenomenon for me, as I can play *every* other game fine without feeling this violently ill, including every other FPS I've come across. Even E.T. doesn't make me feel this ill.

Needless to say I've done some research and most people online point their fingers at the camera sway and the weapon movement.

Is there a way to change or otherwise disable or dial down the camera sway/weapon movement? Perhaps a configuration setting/file or even a mod that does this?

Note I'm primarily concerned  with the Steam version (mentioned just in case it's any different from other versions out there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This are the *console commands* you're looking for I guess.

> - `cl_bob` is "0.02" ["0.02"] view bobbing amount
> - `cl_bobcycle` is "0.6" ["0.6"] view bobbing speed
> - `cl_bobmodel` is "1" ["1"] enables gun bobbing
> - `cl_bobmodel_side` is "0.15" ["0.15"] gun bobbing sideways sway amount
> - `cl_bobmodel_speed` is "7" ["7"] gun bobbing speed
> - `cl_bobmodel_up` is "0.06" ["0.06"] gun bobbing upward movement amount
> - `cl_bobup` is "0.5" ["0.5"] view bobbing adjustment that makes the up    or down swing of the bob last longer

**[Quote Source](http://www.quakewiki.net/darkplaces-wiki/console-variables)**

So happy fraggin'.

Comment: Cool. So if I set `cl_bobmodel` to 0, this will disable the weapon bobbing? What about the camera movement/sway? I'll give this a go to see if it's any better for me, but I think it's the camera that gives me the most problems.

Comment: @Robotnik As far as i can remember, cl_bob is the camera and cl_bobmodel the weapon. That would explain why next to the [] it's gun or view bobbing ;)

Comment: Ah, that's awesome, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: What the square brackets [] indicate? Just the default values?

Comment: @Wrigglenite The answer is also missing the `cl_rollangle` (`cl_rollangle 0`) command which tilts the screen when strafing. May contribute more to motion sickness than the view-bob. I know that edits should preserve the "structure" of the original Q/A and I thought that adding information is allowed as long as it integrates sensibly (I've seen "updates" created by other users on SE). I may ask on meta.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answer, the following commands disable the screen-tilting effect which is used when the player takes damage:

```
v_kickpitch 0
v_kickroll 0
v_kicktime 0
```

[source](https://www.quakewiki.net/archives/console/commands/quake.html)

> `v_kickpitch`
>
> Type: Register
> Default: 0.6
> Description: The distance that the
> screen should move up or down when the player is shot.
>
> `v_kickroll`
>
> Type: Register
> Default: 0.6
> Description: The distance that the
> screen should roll clockwise or counter clockwise when the player is
> shot.
>
> `v_kicktime`
>
> Type: Register
> Default: 0.5
> Description: The amount of time that
> the screen should remain tiled after the player has been shot.

Comment: thank you for these additional commands, they are very useful :)